# Is name of a class an expression?

Tags: java, class, expression

Just out of curiosity, Is name of a class considered as an expression?

Assume I have something like

```
public class Hello{}
```

I know `Hello.class` will return an object of type `Class`. So that is an expression. **But,** can we say `Hello` by itself is an expression? Is it considered as a single value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.1) states about the result of an expression:

> When an expression in a program is evaluated (executed), the result denotes one of three things:
>
> - A variable (§4.12) (in C, this would be called an lvalue)
> - A value (§4.2, §4.3)
> - Nothing (the expression is said to be void)

None of the above matches. Also, if you go through the subsections 8 to 28 of [section 15 of the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html) and [section 6.5.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6), none of the expression types matches. All expression types are described there (see [jls-15.2 Forms of expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2)).

**Conclusion:** Class names are not expressions, but can be part of expressions.